# How to escape spoiler in blockquote that starts with exclamation point

Tags: support, markdown, spoilers, blockquote

How can I "escape" the spoiler syntax when putting some text in a blockquote that starts with an exclamation point?

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/170880/267540

Here is the text that I want in a blockquote

```
!cryptography@lemmy.ml
```

I want it in a blockquote, so I write this

```
> !cryptography@lemmy.ml
```

...but that appears like this

> cryptography@lemmy.ml

I also tried the backslash escape character

```
> \!cryptography@lemmy.ml
```

...but it still appears like this

> cryptography@lemmy.ml

How can I put an item of text in a blockquote that starts with an exclamation point *without* it appearing as a "spoiler"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put an empty `<p></p>` block before it:

```
> <p></p>!cryptography@lemmy.ml
```

> !cryptography@lemmy.ml

No idea why this works, but it does.

Comment: You can use any "empty" HTML, including comments (`<!-- -->`), which you can also use to tell any editors to not remove.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Unicode code point [U+200B `ZERO WIDTH SPACE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) in front of your exclamation point, whether written as a literal character or as a named, decimal, or hexadecimal character entity:

1. literal character `​`:

> ​!secret literal character

2. named entity `&ZeroWidthSpace;`

> ​!secret named entity

3. decimal entity `&#8203;`:

> ​!secret decimal entity

4. hex entity `&#x200B;`:

> ​!secret hex entity

Note how those all work. The interposition of another codepoint than an exclamation point suffices to throw the markdown parser off your trail.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe use backticks like this:

> `!cryptography@lemmy.ml`

... i.e.:

```
> `!cryptography@lemmy.ml`
```